# Difference of static deserialization in Java depending on when serialize the object

Tags: java, serialization, static

I am trying to figure out the (de/)serialization in Java.

I have read, that `static` variables are *not* serialized.

To figure this out, I've made a little example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SerialDemo {

    private static void writeFile() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectOutputStream o=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("foo"));
        Test test = new Test();
        o.writeObject(test);
        o.flush();
    }

    private static Test readFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("foo"));
        return (Test) in.readObject();
    }
}
class Test implements Serializable{
    static Integer i;
    public Test(){
        i = 10;
    }
}
```

Why are there differences between the run of those two main-methods?

*First version:*
Serialize and deserialize in a single run

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

        try {
            // Serialization
            writeFile();
            // Deserialization
            Test deserializedFile = readFile();
            System.out.println(deserializedFile.i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This outputs `10`. But why? I thought the value of `Integer i` was not serialized, since it is `static`.

*Second version:*
Serialize and deserialize in two different runs.

If I first run:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            // Serialization
            writeFile();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And in a second run:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            // Deserialization
            Test deserializedFile = readFile();
            System.out.println(deserializedFile.i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It outputs `null`, as I suggested in *first version* too.

Where is the difference?!

Comment: Don't set static variables in constructors: static variables belong to a class, not an instance. Set them either directly on fields, or in static initializers.

Comment: @GhostCat and to you. Going for the 100k this year?

Comment: @GhostCat shrug. Real work keep getting in the way.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: it is a static variable. It gets initialized in your first example, when you create one instance using the constructor!

In the second example, that constructor is never called, the field stays null!

That is all there is to this. And as you said yourself: the static field is **not** written into that file. The only thing that matters in your two examples is that one version calls the constructor, and the other does not.

Beyond that, there is another misconception here: you write *deserializedFile.i*... That is **conceptually** wrong. You should use *Test.i* instead. Static variables are the same for all instances, their owning scope is the Test class, not some instance of that class!

And just for the record: *deserializedFile* is a very misleading name. That variable represents a deserialized Test object. It is *not* to a file! Names should say what they are about and not lie. This names lies big time!

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, the value `10` is still located inside the static variable `i` since it's within the same run. It's not actually loaded by the `readFile()` method.

In your second example the value is still `10` within the *first* run, but in the second run it's the default value `null` (the constructor is not yet called), calling `readFile()` does not actually load values into `i`.

---

Try calling `deserializedFile.i = null;` before `readFile()` in your first example, and you'll notice the same behaviour occurs as in your second example.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. And have my vote, as we almost came in the same minute :-)

Answer (score 1):

Its working as expected. In your first run the **i** variable is not serialized. What you see is the value that was set in the **Test** constructor and because its static the value is same for all objects of the same class.

In your second run you don't create the Test class via the constructor so the value is not set. Deserialization is not calling the Test constructor and is not deserializing the i value, so you see the correct output null value.